# DBT : Getting error ‘>’ not supported between instances of ‘Table’ and ‘int’

Tags: jinja2, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, dbt

I have to compare the result of query with hardcoded integer value in if condition

```
{%- set query %}
select cast(1 as integer)
{% endset -%}
{%- set main = run_query(query) -%}

{% if execute %}

{% if main > 2 %}
```

Getting below error…

> '>' not supported between instances of 'Table' and 'int'

Comment: @tconbeer : Kindly help on this

Answer (score 2):

The query `select cast(1 as integer)` returns table(single column/single row) and it is not directly comparable with constant integer:

```
{% if main > 2 %}
```

should rather be:

```
{% if (main.columns[0].values()[0]) > 2 %}
```